# Albanese dual to the Picard scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Does anyone have a reference that the Albanese is dual to the Picard scheme (under suitable conditions)?

Edit: In fact, the following is true: $(\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)_{\mathrm{red}})^\vee = \mathrm{Alb}(X)$, and the Picard scheme is reduced (and then smooth and an Abelian scheme) iff equality holds in $\dim H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \geq \dim \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ ("defect of smoothness").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nicest modern reference for the theory of the Albanese that I know of is the appendix to [this](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/Topics%20in%20Absolute%20Anabelian%20Geometry%20I.pdf) article of S. Mochizuki.

Answer (score 7):

I think there are many places where this is written in detail.

A good reference is Birkenake-Lange's book *Complex Abelian Varieties*, Proposition 11.11.6 (page 357), where the statement $\textrm{Pic}^0(M)=\widehat{\textrm{Alb}(M)}$ is proven for any smooth projective variety $M$.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I am interested in the result in positive characteristic.

Answer (score 5):

The original reference is: [On Picard Varieties](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2372231),
Wei-Liang Chow,
American Journal of Mathematics **74**, 895-909 (1952), with references to earlier work by Weil and Igusa.

Answer (score 1):

See also [FGA explained], Corollary 9.5.13 and Remark 9.5.25.

Answer (score -1):

I like very much Mumford's "abelian varieties", which has the advantage to work over any characteristic. enjoy!

Comment: Mumford's Abelian Varieties works only over algebraically closed fields, and has nothing about Albaneses.